# Showing date time with Apex:outputtext

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Is there any way to show the time in a user's timezone using an `<apex:outputText>` tag? I am using the below markup, with no Apex controller:

```
<apex:outputLink rendered="{! fld == 'Due__c'}" onclick="updateDueDate('{!r.Id}');return  false;" styleClass="actionLink">
    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,M/d/yyyy h:mm a}" >
        <apex:param value="{!r[fld]}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:outputLink>
```

The result of this is the date is displaying in GMT timezone. Please let me know how can we show it in the current user's timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but you will have to format it in the controller.
There you can use something like:

```
DateTime.now().format('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss',Timezone);
```

But you will have to do it in the controller. You can't do it in the visualforce page or formula.

Comment: Is `TimeZone` a variable here? what is it set to?

Answer (score 0):

you can read the ansewer is in this post    http://www.laceysnr.com/2011/09/formatting-that-date-one-solution-to.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the only way it worked for me was using outputField instead of output text. This will format to the user local

```
<apex:outputField value="{!date_field__c}"/>
```